# How to find any of I/B/P frames in h264?

Tags: video-streaming, h.264, mpeg-4, bytestream

I need to find any (I/B/P) new frame in h264 byte stream.

I heard about NAL header, but I have such a strange stream:

```
00 00 00 01 09 F0 00 00 00 01 
67 64 00 1E AC B2 01 40 5F F2 
E0 22 00 00 07 D2 00 01 D4 C0 
1E 2C 5C 90 00 00 00 01 68 EB 
C3 CB 22 C0 00 00 01 06 05 FF
```

1. What's mean 0x09 0xF0 between 00 00 00 01 ?
2. How to detect new frame (any of I/B/P) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where to start.

First off `0x09 0xF0` is an access unit delimiter. This is the start of your frame. But note, this is an optional NALU, and may not exist in all frames. Second, a frame can be made up of multiple slices, and each slice can be of type I/P/B. So it is possible to find a frame that contains all three slice types. I can go into more detail on how to determine the slice type, and and how to find the start of a frame if no AUD is present. But both topics are extremely large, and should (And probably do) have their own Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: Looks like you really understand how h264 encoding works, and maybe you have an answer to my question: I have to write mpeg-ts muxer, and need to set PTS (no DTS, - stream doesn't have b-frames).
Can I simply generate it or I need to parse h264 anyway? By the way, I don't need audio in my output stream, - if it's important.

Comment: the AVC bitstream does not contain any timestamps, so you can just generate you own. However, you should check the SPS for VUI paramaters, and if the fixed_frame_rate_flag is set your pts should increment by exactly 90000 * ( ( 2 * num_units_in_tick ) / time_scale). Unless frames were dropped.